# No auth token firebase storage android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am sending images to firebase. but when my upload pictures method starts running, I get `no auth token` printed into my logcat couple of times. I tried using both camera and gallery, but they both make the same output even though my firebase storage rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And my code is:

```
if (fragment3.isAdded()) {
                    EditText plantdetails = (EditText) fragment3.getView().findViewById(R.id.plantdetails);
                    if (plantdetails.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(newPlant.this, "I think you forgot something.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        plants plantss = new plants();

                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newPlant.this);
                        prefs.edit().putString("pldetails", plantdetails.getText().toString()).apply();
                        String pname = prefs.getString("plname","null");
                        String pdate = prefs.getString("pldate","null");
                        String petails = prefs.getString("pldetails","null");
                        plantss.setPlname(pname);
                        plantss.setPldate(pdate);
                        plantss.setPldetails(petails);

                        reference.child("Plants").child(pname).setValue(plantss);


                        try {

                            Fileuploader();
                        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (fragment4.isAdded()){

                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void Fileuploader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String imageid;

        progress.showProgress(newPlant.this,"Loading...",false);
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
        Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(newPlant.this);
        String plname = prefs.getString("plname","null");
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;

        if (getimage !=null){
            while (getimage.moveToNext()) {
                System.out.println("IMAGE IS THIS MY MAN: "+ getimage.getString(0));
               Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0));
               if (bm == null){
                   return;
               }else {
                   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, out);
                   imageid = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + (count++) + "." + getExtension(uri);
                   DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Plants").child(plname).child("PlantImages");
                   String imagekey = reference.push().getKey();
                   reference.child(imagekey).child("ImageID").setValue(imageid);
                   reference.child(imagekey).child("ID").setValue(count2++);

                   System.out.println("IMAGES UPLOADEDDDD: " + imageid);
                   byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
                   StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(imageid);
                   Ref.putBytes(data)
                           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                   // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                                   //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                   //Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   progress.hideProgress();
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(newPlant.this, Donenewplant.class);
                                   startActivity(intent);
                                   finish();
                                   DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(newPlant.this);
                                   Cursor cursor2 = mDatabaseHelper.DeleteDataOfTableImagesAr();
                                   cursor2.moveToNext();
                               }
                           })
                           .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                   // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                   // ...
                                   Toast.makeText(newPlant.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   System.out.println("FAILED:::: "+exception);
                               }
                           });
               }


            }


        }






    }
```

Mainfest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.varroxsystems.plant">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/plant"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/plant"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Donenewplant"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".newPlant" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Splash_screen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.varroxsystems.plant.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So does anyone know a solution for that, or is it just a bug, because I use the same exact code in another app and it works just fine.

EDIT: The other app I use uses a different database, not the same one.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for the info, I edited the post and I tried to provide as less code as possible!